# JdbcTemplate returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

**JdbcTemplate** is returning an empty list when executing the "**query**" method.

```
public List<Loan> getLoanDAO(Employee employee, String s) {
    final String SQL = "SELECT CTLPCODCIA, CTLPCODSUC, CTLPCODTRA, EMPNOMBRE, EMPAPATERN, EMPAMATERN, CTLPCODPRE, "
            + "CTLPTIPPRE, TIPDESPRE, CTLPMONEDA, CTLPESTADO, CTLPMONTOP, CTLPNROCUO, CTLPCUOTA, FLAGTIPOCUOTA, CTLGLOSA, CTLDIASFR, "
            + "CTLDOCADJ, CTLUSUCREA, CTLFECCREA "
            + "FROM HR_CTLPREC_SS INNER JOIN HR_EMPLEADO ON CTLPCODCIA=EMPCODCIA AND CTLPCODSUC=EMPCODSUC AND CTLPCODTRA=EMPCODTRA "
            + "INNER JOIN HR_TIPPRE ON CTLPCODCIA=TIPCODCIA AND CTLPCODSUC=TIPCODSUC AND CTLPTIPPRE=TIPCODPRE "
            + "WHERE TIPFLGEST = '1' AND TIPSELFSERVICE = '1' "
            + "AND CTLPCODCIA = ? AND CTLPCODSUC = ? AND EMPCODTRAJEF = ? AND CTLPESTADO = ? ";
    List<Loan> loans = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new Object[] {
            employee.getCTLPCODCIA(), employee.getCTLPCODSUC(), employee.getCTLPCODTRA(), s }, loanMapper);
    return loans;
}
```

However, when replacing the "?" with the same parameters used in execution and executing in sqldeveloper, it returns 4 rows. I don't know what is wrong since I've been doing de data access code in the same way for all the other entities.

---

### Problem solved

As stated by @Julian:

> JdbcTemplate is a proved spring component used by a huge number of applications so in my opinion it must be a bug in your code.

It was not a problem from **JdbcTemplate**, neither my code. It was an issue from the IDE. I just build my project from scratch using maven console commands and the code worked as intended.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Try adding a space between the `=` and the `?` sign.

Answer (score 1):

JdbcTemplate is a proved spring component used by a huge number of applications so in my opinion it must be a bug in your code.
Not sure what version of Spring you are using but jdbcTemplate.query would expect a Loan Mapper class as one of its arguments. There is no such a mapper present in your code.

I suggest you put a breakpoint just before the query and inspect the employee fields and see if they match the values you are playing in the sqldeveloper.

One other thing that it attracts my attention is the third one where u have EMPCODTRAJEF = ? in the query definition but you use employee.getCTLPCODTRA() as the argument. Obviously I don't know your data model but should it rather be employee.getEMPCODTRAJEF() or the other way around?

Comment: The "employee.getCTLPCODTRA()" is ok. As you say, that is my business logic. And I have also run the code with my IDE in debugger mode to check if employee variables and the "s" variable are the same I use in sqldeveloper. And my "loanMapper" object is also a correct. I just didn't want to put to much code on my post. I know that "loanMapper" works fine because it is used in other methods. Adding loggers to "loanMapper" didn'te help beacuse it's code is never runned. I guess this just makes this problem harder to solve.

Comment: Then if all arguments are correct the only one explanation I can see is that you are pointing to a different schema/database from java than the one from your sqldeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

If this won't work double check your arguments.

```
final String SQL = "SELECT CTLPCODCIA, CTLPCODSUC, CTLPCODTRA, EMPNOMBRE, EMPAPATERN, EMPAMATERN, CTLPCODPRE, "
            + "CTLPTIPPRE, TIPDESPRE, CTLPMONEDA, CTLPESTADO, CTLPMONTOP, CTLPNROCUO, CTLPCUOTA, FLAGTIPOCUOTA, CTLGLOSA, CTLDIASFR, "
            + "CTLDOCADJ, CTLUSUCREA, CTLFECCREA "
            + "FROM HR_CTLPREC_SS INNER JOIN HR_EMPLEADO ON CTLPCODCIA=EMPCODCIA AND CTLPCODSUC=EMPCODSUC AND CTLPCODTRA=EMPCODTRA "
            + "INNER JOIN HR_TIPPRE ON CTLPCODCIA=TIPCODCIA AND CTLPCODSUC=TIPCODSUC AND CTLPTIPPRE=TIPCODPRE "
            + "WHERE CTLPCODCIA=? AND CTLPCODSUC = ? AND EMPCODTRAJEF = ? AND CTLPESTADO = ? "
            + "AND TIPFLGEST='1' AND TIPSELFSERVICE='1'";
```

Add this to `application.properties` to debug your query.
`logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE`

Comment: I see what you did there. Separating the "=" from the column names and "?". I've already tried but got nothing

Comment: Double check your arguments

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge but, what do you mean with "double check"?

Comment: Make sure that arguments in Java match to the arguments which you are using in SQL.

Comment: I've already done that. I used the debugger to check them in runtime. But they are the same.